# npm Unable to Install angular-cli

Tags: angularjs, node.js, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am trying to install angular-cli via npm. I have the recent version of Nodejs and git installed. I am not behind any proxy server(verified it through `netsh winhttp show proxy` as well as through Internet Explorer LAN settings) and there is no problem with my internet connection. When i try to run

`npm install -g angular-cli` then I get the following error

```
C:\Windows\system32>npm install -g angular-cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "angular-cli"
npm ERR! node v7.3.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.192.162:80
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\system32\npm-debug.log
```

I tried cleaning the cache through `npm cache clean` and also tried to change the registry to http:\ via

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

I also tried uninstalling nodejs and reinstalling it again but it is not working. I am getting the same error. Any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this can be caused either by a firewall or a proxy. Can you ping the npm registry host and fetch a simple file?

```
> ping registry.npmjs.org
> npm view npm version
```

If the ping is not successful, check your connection or **disable your firewall**.

Comment: I am not able to ping registry.npmjs.org. The request timed out.

Comment: so you have a connection issue

Comment: i've tried it now and its work on my machine so disable your firewall or check your connection is it okey

Comment: Running npm view npm version resulted in the same error as above. So this could be a firewall issue?

Comment: possible, are you using a proxy? try to use tracert registry.npmjs.org to check the rooting process

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem was with the connection. I disabled the firewall but it didn't work. Used a different ISP to connect to the internet and now the installation was successful.

Answer (score 4):

Setp-1: open windows command prompt then type following command to get the IP address of your proxy server

```
ping your-proxy-name
```

For example:

```
ping myproxy.xyz.com
```

Step-2: open Node.js command prompt and type following command

```
npm config set http-proxy http://your-proxy-ip-retrieved-in-step-1:port
npm config set https-proxy http://your-proxy-ip-retrieved-in-step-1:port
```

For example:

```
npm config set http-proxy http://192.168.192.95:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://192.168.192.95:8080
```

Setp-3: on Node.js command prompt type following command to install angular

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: This worked for me as my corporate proxy was blocking the npm registry url.

Comment: I am happy to know that it worked for you. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

Future viewers: Try below approach (it worked for me)

Go to nodejs installed location (path may be different in your case)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

Add below entry in the npmrc file then save it

```
strict-ssl=false
```

Then try installing angular cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of issues usually happen when you are behind a proxy or a firewall that blocks npm from fetching the requested packaged.

If you know your proxy address and port, open a console and set your HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables before running npm, as follows:

```
set HTTP_PROXY = "http://<proxy server name or IP address>:<proxy port>"
set HTTPS_PROXY = ... ;same as above 

npm install <package_name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues and figured that we need to combine the proxy and the install command together like below and it worked for me. Hope it works for you people. Thanks!!

npm --proxy http://username:password@proxyURL:port install -g @angular/cli --without-ssl --insecure

Answer (score 0):

You need to override your proxy settings to install angular CLI.
Try executing below command :

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

This will override your proxy and you do not need to make any changes to your connections or firewall. Once this command executes successfully try installing angular CLI using below command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Refer [this link](https://stackabuse.com/npm-error-failed-to-fetch-from-registry-when-installing-module/) for more details on this.

This solved problems for me. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was disconnect my computer from my wifi and connect back. Hope this helps someone else.