# NPM Installation issue in CMD

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I am trying to install CLI, getting below error occurred.

`>C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\fshaik.PROTECH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-02T22_07_53_089Z-debug.log`

---

Please help..

Thanks

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Comment: Frankly, npm told you already everything.

Comment: possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41280528/3621001)

Comment: network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.20.35:80
   - here is problem, check your connection or mb there some other problems that node cant access registry.npmjs.org/