# npm Install Boostrap font-awesome network error

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, npm-install

I'm doing a pluralsight tutorial but i'm behind some pretty strick firewalls.
When I try run `npm install bootstrap font-awesome` I get this:

```
PS D:\PluralSight\HelloWorldDemo> npm install bootstrap font-awesome
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bootstrap" "font-    awesome"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.27.35:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network     settings.npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\PluralSight\HelloWorldDemo\npm-debug.log
PS D:\PluralSight\HelloWorldDemo> npm start
```

I tried to `ping` *104.16.27.35* but it timed out.

Comment: Can look at the following, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280429/npm-unable-to-install-angular-cli

Comment: Hi Mani, i defo have connection issue, i'm wondering if there's a way to install it locally maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you install [font-awesome](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome) and [bootstrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap) individually by running

```
npm install font-awesome --save
npm install bootstrap --save
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end i got a copy of the files from NPM myself, and put them into the Nodes_module folder, then i just referenced them in the code. So I never have to call npm install. 
Hopefully that helps someone like me who's stuck behind a locked down internet connection.