# Error While Installing @angular/cli@next --global in windows

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have installed Node.js and NPM successfully in my machine. This is my corporate machine and it needs to be connected to the required vpn for internet connection.
While installing angular-cli i am getting the below error:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>npm install @angular/cli@next --global
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.16.17.35:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-30T19_09_37_660Z-debug.log
```

Can any one please explain me what needs to be done here? Early response is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm Unable to Install angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280429/npm-unable-to-install-angular-cli)

Comment: @Roy: No, in my configuration for proxy i have PAC file in the url.

Comment: This helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660936/using-npm-behind-corporate-proxy-pac